# Generic type BoundedComponent struct

Tags: c#, operator-keyword, implicit

I want to do a struct for boundedElements like number that has a max and min value. However I'm stuck on how to do this.
Here is an example of a property. The setfield method is just a method to set a property and raise a property changed event.

```
private BoundedComponent<int> nbOfItems = new BoundedComponent<int> (1, int.MaxValue);

public int NbOfItems 
        {
            get => nbOfItems ;
            set => SetField(ref nbOfItems, value);
        }


protected bool SetField<T>(
            ref T field,
            T value,
            [CallerMemberName]
            string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
                return false;

            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
```

and here is my struct

```
public struct BoundedComponent<T> where T : struct, IComparable<T>
    {
        private T value;
        private T minValue;
        private T maxValue;

        public BoundedComponent(T minValue, T maxValue)
        {
            this.minValue = minValue;
            this.maxValue = maxValue;
            value = minValue;
        }

        public static implicit operator T(BoundedComponent<T> d)
        {
            return d.value;
        }

        public static implicit operator BoundedComponent<T>(T val)
        {
            value = BoundValue(val);
        }

        private T BoundValue(T value) 
        {
            return value.CompareTo(maxValue) > 0 ? maxValue 
                : value.CompareTo(minValue) < 0 ? minValue : value;
        }
    }
```

However I cannot do that because the implicit operator is a static method so I don't have access to the min and max values of the bounded element I want to check.

How can I do such a thing ?

I tried the above method and also using a class with a property Value however I cannot use it inside my setfield method since properties cant be passed by reference.

Comment: How about making an extra `SetField` for `BoundedComponent`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BoundedComponent` should *not* have a conversion from `T`. An instance of `T` simply does not have enough information to create an instance of `BoundedComponent`. Namely, `T` does not have any information about its minimum and maximum values.

I would make the `BoundValue` method actually *set* `value`, and rename it to `Set`.

```
public struct BoundedComponent<T> where T : struct, IComparable<T>
{
    private T value;
    // consider making these readonly
    private readonly T minValue;
    private readonly T maxValue;

    public BoundedComponent(T minValue, T maxValue)
    {
        this.minValue = minValue;
        this.maxValue = maxValue;
        value = minValue;
    }

    public static implicit operator T(BoundedComponent<T> d)
    {
        return d.value;
    }

    public void Set(T value) 
    {
        this.value = value.CompareTo(maxValue) > 0 ? maxValue 
            : value.CompareTo(minValue) < 0 ? minValue : value;
    }
}
```

You should create a new `SetField` method for setting `BoundedComponent`s. As you found out, you cannot use the existing `SetField`.

Even if you could, the existing `SetField`'s logic is incorrect for `BoundedComponent`s. Suppose the call `SetField(ref nbOfItems, -1)` actually works - if `nbOfItems` was initially `1`, this would have unexpectedly raised `OnPropertyChanged` event.

You should record the old value, try to call `Set`, and compare the old value with the current value to see if it changed:

```
protected bool SetField<T>(
    ref BoundedComponent<T> field,
    T value,
    [CallerMemberName]
    string propertyName = null)
    where T: struct, IComparable<T>
{
    T old = field;
    field.Set(value);
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(old, field))
        return false;
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that works. I wish you a good day.